# weird behavior of JS functions in an if statement, WHY?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why the following code will return  *“obvious”*, *“surprise!”* (and lastly *“how come?”*). It should  return *"expected"*, isn't it?
In the first `if` we used anonymous functions, in the second we used 'named' functions.

```
var a = 5;
if (a == 5) {
    var b = function () {
        return "obvious";
    };
} else {
    var b = function () {
        return "never";
    };
}

if (a == 5) {
    function c() {
        return "expected";
    }
} else {
    function c() {
        return "surprise!";
    }
    function d() {
        return "how come?";
    }
}

alert(b());
alert(c());
alert(d());
```

So this means, `function a(){} is NOT equal to var a = function (){}`.

So, the second question, why JS needs this peculiar behavior? What's the benefit of this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All variable declarations and function declarations are hoisted to the top of the scope, in this case the top of the script. This means the code is interpreted as if it was,

```
var a,b;
function c() { 
    return "expected"; 
} 
function c() { 
    return "surprise!"; 
} 
function d() { 
    return "how come?"; 
} 

a = 5; 
if (a == 5) { 
    b = function () { 
        return "obvious"; 
    }; 
} else { 
    b = function () { 
        return "never"; 
    }; 
} 

if (a == 5) { 
} 
else { 
} 

alert(b()); 
alert(c()); 
alert(d());
```

Note that the last if statement is empty as all the function declarations they contained were hoisted. The second declaration of the function `c` obscures the first.

I recommend you avoid using funciton declaration syntax in a block statement. It is techincally not legal JavaScript but every browser supports it even though it leads to confusion as you have noted.

> function a(){} is NOT equal to var a = function (){}.

Correct. This has never been the case.

> So, the second question, why JS needs this peculiar behavior? What's the benefit of this ?

JavaScript hoists function declarations to allow function declared later in the script to be used by function earlier in a script. This allows much more flexiblity in code organization.

Answer (score 7):

No, it shouldn't, because the semantics of function definition statements are not what you apparently think they are.

Function definition statements are always hoisted up to the top of the enclosing function (or scope).  When there's more than one function definition statement with the same name, the last one wins. It's not a dynamic execution-time thing. Putting function definition statements inside conditional code blocks should really be syntactically forbidden, but it itsn't.  Just don't do it.

You can of course use function *instantiation* expressions to create function objects that you assign to variables. That would work as you expect.

Comment: I think you mean function **declaration**. But Mozilla[1] has an extension that treats what appears to be a function delcaration inside a block as a function statement, so it isn't "hoisted" and is conditionally evaluated, giving the appearance of conditional declarations. Other browsers treat them as declarations and behave as you say. 1. Unfortunately I can't test in Mozilla or Firefox to see if that's still the case. I'll check later.

Comment: Well perhaps it's "declaration"; the distinction is (as you clearly know) that there's a facility for function *instantiation* that's part of the syntax of expressions, and then there's a *statement* that defines and declares a named function. They have some effects in common, but the statement is distinctly different than the instantiation sub-expression.

Answer (score 1):

@Pointy is correct. Function c() and d() are being declared before the first if statement is being evaluated. That's why when you call the alerts, they do what they do.